# [Abp]Sometimes the web api cannot authenticate via accessToken

Tags: authentication, jwt, abp

I am deploying an abp applications to azure web app. I have a web api, an identity server, and a react application.

I have problem is sometime when react application request to api with the accessToken but the api cannot authenticate.

Here is the code I tried to print the claim list from current principal.

```
_logger.LogWarning("Request.Path: " + _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Path.Value);
            foreach (var claim in _principalAccessor.Principal.Claims)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("claim.type: " + claim.Type);
                _logger.LogWarning("claim.valueTYpe: " + claim.ValueType);
                _logger.LogWarning("claim.value: " + claim.Value);
            }
```

but some requests has the claim log but some requests not